# Programmatically focus on UITextView is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextview, first-responder

Before closing the post as **duplicate**,believe me,i am searching this for 2 days but still nothing.
I will try to be as clear as possible:

I have a view with a textview.I need to set focus automatically on the textview so the keyboard ill appear.

PostView.h

```
@interface PostView : UIViewController{
UITextView *txtPesto;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *txtPesto;
@end
```

PostView.m

```
#import "PostView.h"
@implementation PostView
@synthesize txtPesto;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
   [txtPesto becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

For some very strange reason my code is not working,although i have tried many samples and different approaches.
Any help?

Comment: did you connected the `IBOUtlet` in xib ?

Comment: I have dragged the TextView's delegate to File's Owner.Yes.

Comment: Please add the `[txtPesto becomeFirstResponder];` to viewDidAppear method.

Comment: -(void)viewDidAppear
{
    [txtPesto becomeFirstResponder];
}
didn't work

Comment: You wrote that you have dragged textView's delegate to Files Owner, but what about IBOutlet in xib? right click on textView, and "new referncing outlet", maybe that will be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from my comment (for closing question):
Right click on textView, and "new referncing outlet", maybe that will be helpful?

Comment: Pavel Katunin Thank you this was the problem.I dont know why Referencing outlets was not connected on the first place!

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `txtPesto` twice in your .h file:

```
@interface PostView : UIViewController{
    UITextView *txtPesto;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *txtPesto;
@end
```

When you declare it as a property, you don't need to do it again. So remove the extra declaration, and just use this:

```
@interface PostView : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *txtPesto;

@end
```

I don't see any other reason that `becomeFirstResponder` wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok,did this and believe me didn't work.I made a new project,and manage to get it work.My only difference was that my original project is 4.3 targeted.

Comment: It's not correct. If you are declared like int x; and @property (nonatomic) int x; is it declared twice ? what is wrong with writing like this ?